# Parent element does not support property elements

Tags: java, javafx

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.scene.control.*?>
<?import java.lang.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane?>

<BorderPane maxHeight="-Infinity" maxWidth="-Infinity"
    minHeight="-Infinity" minWidth="-Infinity" prefHeight="576.0"
    prefWidth="722.0" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1">
    <top>

    </top>
    <center>
        <children>
            <fx:include source="chld.fxml" />

        </children>

    </center>
</BorderPane>
```

chld.fxml

```
<children>
      <HBox id="hbox_top" AnchorPane.leftAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.rightAnchor="0.0">
         <Label fx:id="sessionLabel" prefHeight="20.0" text="" onMouseClicked="#mClicked"/>  
      </HBox>
   </children>
```

I written this code to include child document another fxml file.but whwn u try this i get following
 error.

```
   Parent element does not support property elements.
```

Answer (score 1):

It's not legal to have a `<children>` tag inside the `<center>` tag. You just want

```
<center>
    <fx:include source="child.fxml"/>
</center>
```

And then child.fxml should look like a regular fxml file, i.e. the root element should be some kind of `Parent` (no `<children>` tag here either).

Comment: You have other errors too, e.g. since the `<HBox>` in your child.fxml file is being placed in a `BorderPane`, you can't set `AnchorPane` properties on it. The answer just gives the reasons for the error you posted.

Comment: i remove the children tag and center from Border Pane.but t give the following.HBox is not a valid type

Comment: i only add the follwing.<Label fx:id="sessionLabel" prefHeight="20.0" text="" onMouseClicked="#mClicked"/>
but still not working

Comment: Well, that's a different error, so a different question. But you're not going to get very far by trying to solve every single error by posting to a forum. I recommend reading the [tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/get-started-tutorial/fxml_tutorial.htm#JFXST206) and the [Introduction to FXML](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/fxml/doc-files/introduction_to_fxml.html); then try to fix the errors yourself and post questions when you get stuck.